# select a set of values from tuple with run-time index

Tags: c++, containers, c++17

Short introduction to my questions:
i'm trying to implement a "sort of" relational database using stl containers. This is just for fun/educational purpose, so no need for answers like "use this library", "this is absolutely useless" and so on.
I know title is a little bit confusing at this point, but we will reach the point (suggestions for improvement to title are really welcome).

I proceeded with little steps:

1. i can build table as vector of maps from columns name to their values => `std::vector<std::map<std::string, some_variant>>`. It's simple and it represents what i need.
2. wait, i can just store column's names once and access values with their index. => `std::vector<std::vector<some_variant>>`.As simple as point 1, but faster than that.
3. wait wait, in a database a table is literrally a sequence of tuple => `std::vector<std::tuple<args...>>`. This is cool, it represents exactly what i'm doing, correct type without variant and even faster than the other.

Note: the "faster than" was measured for
1000000 records with a simple loop like this:

```cpp
std::random_device dev;
std::mt19937 gen(dev());
std::uniform_int_distribution<long> rand1_1000(1, 1000);
std::uniform_real_distribution<double> rand1_10(1.0, 10.0);

void fill_1()
{
    using my_variant = std::variant<long, long long, double, std::string>;
    using values = std::map<std::string, my_variant>;
    using table = std::vector<values>;

    table t;
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
        t.push_back({ {"col_1", rand1_1000(gen)}, {"col_2", rand1_1000(gen)}, {"col_3", rand1_10(gen)} });
    std::cout << "size:" << t.size() << "\n";//just to prevent optimization
}
```

1. 2234101600ns - avg:2234
2. 446344100ns - avg:446
3. 132075400ns - avg:132

**INSERT:**
No problem with any of these solutions, insert are as simple as pushing back elements as in the example.

**SELECT:**
1 and 2 are simple, but 3 is tricky.

So, finally, questions:

1. **Memory usage**: there is a lot of overhead using solution 1 and 2 in term of used memory. So, 3 seems to be again the right choice here.
   For the example with 1 million records of 2 `long`s and a `double` i was expecteing something near 4MB*2 for longs and 8MB for doubles plus some overhead for vectors, maps and variants where used. Instead we have (measured with windows task manager, not extremely accurate, i know):

   1.340 MB

   2.120 MB

   3.31 MB

   **Am i missing something?** Other than reserving the right size in advance or `shrink_to_fit` after the insert loop?
2. **Is there a way to run-time retrieve some tuple field as in the case of a select statement?**

```cpp
using my_tuple = std::tuple<long, long, string,  double>;
std::vector<my_tuple> table;
int to_select;//this could be a vector of columns to select obviosly
std::cin>>to_select;
auto result = select (table, to_select);
```

**Do you see any chance to implement this last line in any way?**
We have two problem for what i see: the result type should take the the type from the starting tuple and then, actually perform the selection of desired fields.

I read a lot of answers about that, they all talk about contiguous indexes using `make_index_sequence` or complile-time known index.
I also found [this article](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/cplusplus/getting-tuple-elements-with-runtime-index.html), very interesting, but not really useful for this case.

Comment: access tuple with run time index means that types in tuple inside have to be uniform. If they are uniform you should not use `tuple` but `std::array` and as a result there is not problem accessing it with run time index. Other explanation you do not relay need tuple with run time index.

Comment: In all cases, you might have `some_variant result = select(table, to_select);`

Comment: @MarekR yes, is the same result of the article in the link, uniform type for the tuple. I think you can agree with me that's not so useful in a database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable but it is strange:

```cpp
template<size_t candidate, typename ...T>
constexpr std::variant<T...> helperTupleValueAt(const std::tuple<T...>& t, size_t index)
{
    if constexpr (candidate >= sizeof...(T)) {
        throw std::logic_error("out of bounds");
    } else {
        if (candidate == index) {
            return std::variant<T...>{ std::in_place_index<candidate>, std::get<candidate>(t) };
        } else {
            return helperTupleValueAt<candidate + 1>(t, index);
        }
    }
}

template<typename ...T>
std::variant<T...> tupleValueAt(const std::tuple<T...>& t, size_t index)
{
    return helperTupleValueAt<0>(t, index);
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/FQJd4chAFVSg5eSy

Comment: Since you marked `helperTupleValueAt` as `constexpr`, any reason why `tupleValueAt` is not `constexpr`? Besides, huge +1. This is very clever.

Comment: I just forget about it.

Comment: yeah, it's strange but clever, i like it.
Anyway, at this point i think we must go around the first problem using `variant`s and then use `vector<tuple<variant...>>` as return type of the `select` method.

Comment: Had to improve code to handle tuples with multiple fields with same type. I wonder if there is a way to reduce list of types to be unique so `std::variant` is easier to handle.

Comment: @MarekR oh right, that would be great but i can't figure out how.
I'm going to accept your answer, but for my project i'll choose the solution 2, cause it seems more consistet to me (i can do select and retutrn an object that is still a table with less columns).