# How to properly replace boost::variant by std::variant?

Tags: c++, boost

Using `boost:variant`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>

template <size_t n, typename... T>
boost::variant<T...> _tuple_index(size_t i, const std::tuple<T...>& tpl) {
    if (i == n)
        return std::get<n>(tpl);
    else if (n == sizeof...(T) - 1)
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of Index");
    else
        return _tuple_index<(n < sizeof...(T)-1 ? n+1 : 0)>(i, tpl);
}
template <typename... T>
boost::variant<T...> tuple_index(size_t i, const std::tuple<T...>& tpl) {
    return _tuple_index<0>(i, tpl);
}

template <typename T>
auto tuple_len(T &tpl) {
    return std::tuple_size<T>::value;
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, double, double, int> t("123", 4.5, 6.7, 8);
    for(int i = 0; i != tuple_len(t); ++i) {
        std::cout << tuple_index(i, t) << std::endl; // works with boost
    }
}
```

Replace `boost::variant` by `std::variant`, added a helper to stream `std::variant`:

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

template <size_t n, typename... T>
std::variant<T...> _tuple_index(size_t i, const std::tuple<T...>& tpl) {
    if (i == n)
        return std::get<n>(tpl);
    else if (n == sizeof...(T) - 1)
        throw std::out_of_range("Out of Index");
    else
        return _tuple_index<(n < sizeof...(T)-1 ? n+1 : 0)>(i, tpl);
}
template <typename... T>
std::variant<T...> tuple_index(size_t i, const std::tuple<T...>& tpl) {
    return _tuple_index<0>(i, tpl);
}

template <typename T>
auto tuple_len(T &tpl) {
    return std::tuple_size<T>::value;
}

// added helper to stream std::variant
template <typename T0, typename ... Ts>
std::ostream & operator<< (std::ostream & s, std::variant<T0, Ts...> const & v) { 
    std::visit([&](auto && arg){ s << arg;}, v); 
    return s;
}

int main()
{
    std::tuple<std::string, double, double, int> t("123", 4.5, 6.7, 8);
    for(int i = 0; i != tuple_len(t); ++i) {
        std::cout << tuple_index(i, t) << std::endl; // doesn't work anymore
    }
}
```

The compilation remain error:

```
$ clang++ -v                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            [17:37:47]
Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin

$ clang++ -std=c++17 isostd.cpp

isostd.cpp:8:16: error: no viable conversion from returned value of type 'const typename tuple_element<1UL, tuple<basic_string<char>, double, double, int> >::type' (aka 'const __type_pack_element<1UL, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>') to function return
      type 'std::variant<basic_string<char>, double, double, int>'
        return std::get<n>(tpl);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
isostd.cpp:12:16: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '_tuple_index<1, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>' requested here
        return _tuple_index<(n < sizeof...(T)-1 ? n+1 : 0)>(i, tpl);
               ^
isostd.cpp:16:12: note: in instantiation of function template specialization '_tuple_index<0, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>' requested here
    return _tuple_index<0>(i, tpl);
           ^
isostd.cpp:35:22: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'tuple_index<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>' requested here
        std::cout << tuple_index(i, t) << std::endl; // doesn't work anymore
                     ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/variant:1142:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const typename tuple_element<1UL, tuple<basic_string<char>, double, double, int> >::type'
      (aka 'const __type_pack_element<1UL, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>') to 'const std::__1::variant<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int> &' for 1st argument
  variant(const variant&) = default;
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/variant:1143:3: note: candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'const typename tuple_element<1UL, tuple<basic_string<char>, double, double, int> >::type'
      (aka 'const __type_pack_element<1UL, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>') to 'std::__1::variant<std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int> &&' for 1st argument
  variant(variant&&) = default;
  ^
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/include/c++/v1/variant:1155:13: note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure [with _Arg = const double &, $1 = 0, $2 = 0, $3 = 0, _Tp = double]: no member named 'value' in
      'std::__1::__find_detail::__find_unambiguous_index_sfinae<double, std::__1::basic_string<char>, double, double, int>'
  constexpr variant(_Arg&& __arg) noexcept(
            ^
1 error generated.
```

How can I properly replace boost:variant by std::variant?

I aware of the reference: [What are the differences between std::variant and boost::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40201371/what-are-the-differences-between-stdvariant-and-boostvariant)

> Boost.Variant includes recursive_variant, which allows a variant to contain itself. They're essentially special wrappers around a pointer to a boost::variant, but they are tied into the visitation machinery.

If I understand correctly, there is no way to finish the replace?

Comment: Simpler repro: https://godbolt.org/z/X37pRo https://godbolt.org/z/UOsGFT

Comment: Here I've answer similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/56886345/1387438 and provided [working example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dBtgVc84JJGXGfyy) of exactly same problem using `std::variant`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you have duplicate types in your variant some of the [constructors](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/variant) are disabled:

> This overload only participates in overload resolution if there is exactly one occurrence of T in Types...

You need to use the constructor with an explicit type index:

```
return std::variant<T...>(std::in_place_index<n>, std::get<n>(tpl));
```

Your original boost code has [undefined behaviour](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost/variant.html#id-1.3.46.5.5.3.4):

> Each type specified as a template argument to variant must be distinct after removal of qualifiers. Thus, for instance, both `variant<int, int>` and `variant<int, const int>` have undefined behavior.

The standard libary implementation does support duplicate types and therefore prevents you from accidentally constructing an ambigous variant. For example what should the following do:

```
variant<std::string, double, double, int> t = 4.5;
```

With boost it is UB, either of the `double` values might be initialised or it might do something completely different. The standard library explitly makes this a compiler error so that you have to choose which of your `double`s you want to initialise.

Comment: [Proof of Concept](https://godbolt.org/z/79hQ8N) (Boost on the left, STL on the right).