# Construct a std::variant out of a boost::variant

Tags: c++, boost, variant, boost-variant

I'm trying to construct a `std::variant` out of a `boost::variant`. In practice, I'm trying to define a function with the following signature:

```
template <typename... Types>
std::variant<Types...>
boostvar2stdvar(boost::variant<Types...> input);
```

I've seen the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56956221/how-to-properly-replace-boostvariant-by-stdvariant?noredirect=1&lq=1), but in that case it's converting a tuple to a std::variant, not a boost::variant. I need my function to take a boost::variant directly. Is there an easy way to do that?

Comment: Do you know what `boost::apply_visitor` does, and how to use it?

Comment: Honestly I've never used more than `boost::get<>`, but hopefully I can learn it @SamVarshavchik

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I tried up to now, but honestly I'm lost. I've somehow understood the first examples, but I don't see how to use it

Comment: I meant these ones: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.variant 

How would you use the boost::apply_visitor the fill the variant? @SamVarshavchik

Comment: Pretty much how it's shown there, except that the visitors return the `std::variant`, instead of `void`, and each visitor constructs the `std::variant` from the visited value and return it, and `apply_visitor` then returns the constructed variant.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you can visit all elements types and return the desired variant from there:

```
template <typename... Types> auto b2std(boost::variant<Types...> const& input) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(
        [](auto const& v) -> std::variant<Types...> { return v; }, input);
}
```

When used like this

```
auto x = b2std(boost::variant<int, std::string, double>{"hello world"});
```

Then type of x matches the expected:

```
static_assert(
    std::is_same_v<std::variant<int, std::string, double>, decltype(x)>);
```

### Live

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/638a65cdd0d69b58)**

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <variant>
#include <iostream>

template <typename... Types> auto b2std(boost::variant<Types...> const& input) {
    return boost::apply_visitor(
        [](auto const& v) -> std::variant<Types...> { return v; }, input);
}

int main() {
    auto x = b2std(boost::variant<int, std::string, double>{"hello world"});
    static_assert(
        std::is_same_v<std::variant<int, std::string, double>, decltype(x)>);
}
```